# AWS ACM Custom CSR

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-acm

I'd like the public certificate I have generated on AWS ACM to use my custom CSR details, e.g company name, country et cetera. Is this possible? I have gone through the docs but haven't found out a solution. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I found out it's possible only while using a private CA.